# Python message partition error

Tags: python, data-partitioning

I'm receiving the following message trough TCP:

```
{"message": "Start", "client": "134.106.74.21", "type": 1009}<EOM>
```

but when I'm trying to partition that

```
msg.partition( "<EOM>" )
```

I'm getting the following array:

('{\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00m\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00s\x00\x00\x00a\x00
\x00\x00g\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00#
\x00\x00\x00B\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x00G\x00\x00\x00I\x00\x00\x00N\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00
\x00A\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00
\x00;\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00
\x001\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x006\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x007\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00
\x001\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00
\x000\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x00;\x00\x00\x00#\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x00N\x00\x00\x00D\x00\x00
\x00"\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00c\x00\x00\x00l\x00\x00\x00i\x00\x00
\x00e\x00\x00\x00n\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"\x00
\x00\x001\x00\x00\x003\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x006
\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x007\x00\x00\x004\x00\x00\x00.\x00\x00\x001\x00\x00\x002\x00\x00
\x005\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00,\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00t\x00\x00\x00y\x00
\x00\x00p\x00\x00\x00e\x00\x00\x00"\x00\x00\x00:\x00\x00\x00 \x00\x00\x002\x00\x00\x000
\x00\x00\x000\x00\x00\x005\x00\x00\x00}\x00\x00\x00<\x00\x00\x00E\x00\x00\x00O\x00\x00\x00M
\x00\x00\x00>\x00\x00\x00{"message": "Start", "client": "134.106.74.21", "type": 1009}', 
'', '')

**Updated**

```
try:                    
    #Check if there are messages, if don't than throwing an exception otherwise continue
    ans = self.request.recv( 20480 )                        
    if( ans ):                        
          recv = self.getMessage( recv + ans )
    else:
          #Master client disconnected
          break
except:
 ...

def getMessage( self, msg ):
        print( "masg:" + msg );   
        aSplit = msg.partition( "<EOM>" )                                                                  
        while( aSplit[ 1 ] == "<EOM>" ):
            self.recvMessageHandler( json.loads( aSplit[ 0 ] ) )            
            #Get the new message id any
            msg = aSplit[ 3 ]      
            aSplit = msg.partition( "<EOM>" )
        return msg;
```

The problem has occurred when I'm trying to add two strings.

```
recv + ans
```

Comment: What is the partion method? I think is perhaps a part of your code (not library).

Comment: This is a built in function:http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `print msg.encode("hex")` then you will likely see that this is exactly what is in the string.

In any case, you may have noticed that every 4th byte of the result is one of the characters that you expected. This suggests that you have a UCS4 Unicode string that you are not handling properly.

Did you receive UCS4 encoded bytes? If so then you should be stuffing them into a unicode string u"".append(stuff). But if you are receiving UCS4-encoded bytes and you have any influence over the sender, you really should get things changed to transmit and receive UTF-8 encoded strings since that is more normal over network connections.

Are you sure that the 5 literal bytes < E O M > are indeed the delimiter that you need to use for partitioning. Or is it supposed to be the single byte ASCII code named EOM? Or is it a UCS4 encoded `u"<EOM>"` ?